# How to create AngularJS app with all views defined in one file?

Tags: angularjs

I want to create an app using AngularJS that is contained in one file. Something similar to jQuery Mobile's multi-page template. It would be nice to define several divs with `ng-controller`, each of which would represent a controller with a template. Instead, angular-ui-router seems to require a `templateUrl` or a `template` string. Is there an elegant way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure , you can put your templates into [`script`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3ascript) tag directives like this:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="page1.html">

    <h1>Page 1</h1> <b>markup</b>

</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="page2.html">

    <h2>Page 2</h2> here we go

</script>
```

And then customize the `routeProvider` in this way:

```
$routeProvider.when('/page1', {

  templateUrl : "page1.html"

}).when('/page2', {

  templateUrl : "page2.html"

}).otherwise({

  redirectTo: 'page1' 

});
```

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/akd7gX?p=preview

Comment: Nice, just the way I wanted. Haven't encountered `text/ng-template` in any AngularJS tutorial.

Comment: The official tutorial takes advantage of It. Take a look at it.